# Trouble saving iptables

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables, openvpn

I am having some issues with removing an iptable entry I have entered.

I added

```
-A PREROUTING -d 95.211.213.149/32 -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1194
```

To experiment with putting openvpn traffic over 443 but it failed i did not like the results.

My 443 traffic to my web server is no longer working as i can not seem to get rid of this rule.

I have attempted to remove the rule from /etc/iptables.rules  saving then restarting but the rule comes back even after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try doing this `iptables -D PREROUTING -d 95.211.213.149/32 -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1194` then `iptables-save` or `sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"`

Also do you have any program that is like ConfigServer Firewall (csf) installed that is managing your firewall?

If you are new to iptables I would read up on [Iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) here.

Comment: Thanks I did that and it worked but funny thing is I could have sworn i tired it I guess i did not have the right option in there. Issue is resolved now

Comment: @user219937 Glad to hear the issue is resolved! :)